# How to add kableExtra table into RMarkdown Powerpoint slides

Tags: r, powerpoint, kableextra

I'm attempting to add a table into an RMarkdown Powerpoint Presentation using the `kableExtra` package. Initially, I tried to run the code without `always_use_html` in my YAML and the following error appeared.

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting pptx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Execution halted
```

After adding `always_allow_html` to my YAML, my table is still not appearing as desired in my slide [image: Slide Image].

My table should look something like this

[image: Kable]

Does anyone perhaps know how to embed a `kableExtra` table in Rmarkdown slides?

Here is my full code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: powerpoint_presentation
always_use_html: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


## Table

```{r table}
library(kableExtra)
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))

data %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  kable_styling()

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try `kbl()` instead of `kable()`:

```
library(kableExtra)
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))

data %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

Comment: for some odd reason, the table in my pptx doesn't change when I change ```kable()``` to ````kbl()```

Answer (score 0):

kable() renders to html in the viewer pane when run live, and can knit to html.

Office docs don't handle the html.

Options

1. include, pass a table to the default powerpoint style for your document with .rmd.

See:https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE

2. use officer with officemarkdown
   [Officer bookdown summary](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/office-documents-generation.html#templates)
   -advanced styling to build a custom template can be done for reproducible
   -you can save to powerpoint, then use table style editing to tweak, vs. setting the styling with style_type, style_id,style_name parameters in officedown